# Cannot deserialize the current JSON array into type from when response is xml

Tags: c#, arrays, xml

I have the following response xml format from Microsoft:

```
<SuggestResponse xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <Query>state of decay 2</Query>
    <ResultSets>
        <SuggestResults>
            <Source>dcatall-products</Source>
            <FromCache>false</FromCache>
            <Type>product</Type>
            <Suggests>
                <Product>
                    <Curated>false</Curated>
                    <Source>Games</Source>
                    <Title>State of Decay 2</Title>
                    <Url>//www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/p/state-of-decay-2/9nt4x7p8b9nb</Url>
                    <ImageUrl>//store-images.s-microsoft.com/image/apps.47366.14425140369408817.dca0bcd1-c06c-4345-8a00-fe5bfaff3665.45f69514-da1a-43cd-a1ec-109fe5e54d24?w=150&amp;h=150</ImageUrl>
                    <Metas>
                        <Meta>
                            <Key>BigCatalogId</Key>
                            <Value>9NT4X7P8B9NB</Value>
                        </Meta>
                        <Meta>
                            <Key>ProductType</Key>
                            <Value>Game</Value>
                        </Meta>
                        <Meta>
                            <Key>Icon</Key>
                            <Value>//store-images.s-microsoft.com/image/apps.47366.14425140369408817.dca0bcd1-c06c-4345-8a00-fe5bfaff3665.45f69514-da1a-43cd-a1ec-109fe5e54d24</Value>
                        </Meta>
                        <Meta>
                            <Key>ImageHeight</Key>
                            <Value>300</Value>
                        </Meta>
                        <Meta>
                            <Key>ImageWidth</Key>
                            <Value>300</Value>
                        </Meta>
                        <Meta>
                            <Key>ImageType</Key>
                            <Value>Logo</Value>
                        </Meta>
                    </Metas>
                </Product>
                <Product>
                    <Curated>false</Curated>
                    <Source>Games</Source>
                    <Title>State of Decay 2: Independence Pack</Title>
                    <Url>//www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/p/state-of-decay-2-independence-pack/9n0jhbm3618s</Url>
                    <ImageUrl>//store-images.s-microsoft.com/image/apps.19309.13920304356617547.62bf0ed6-7d21-4166-9bc0-99b6d7154bd1.e3af862c-7d10-4e9d-8f68-2c9a70d610b1?w=150&amp;h=150</ImageUrl>
                    <Metas>
                        <Meta>
                            <Key>BigCatalogId</Key>
                            <Value>9N0JHBM3618S</Value>
                        </Meta>
                        <Meta>
                            <Key>ProductType</Key>
                            <Value>Durable</Value>
                        </Meta>
                        <Meta>
                            <Key>Icon</Key>
                            <Value>//store-images.s-microsoft.com/image/apps.19309.13920304356617547.62bf0ed6-7d21-4166-9bc0-99b6d7154bd1.e3af862c-7d10-4e9d-8f68-2c9a70d610b1</Value>
                        </Meta>
                        <Meta>
                            <Key>ImageHeight</Key>
                            <Value>1080</Value>
                        </Meta>
                        <Meta>
                            <Key>ImageWidth</Key>
                            <Value>1080</Value>
                        </Meta>
                        <Meta>
                            <Key>ImageType</Key>
                            <Value>BoxArt</Value>
                        </Meta>
                    </Metas>
                </Product>
                <Product>
                    <Curated>false</Curated>
                    <Source>Games</Source>
                    <Title>State Of Decay 2: Ultimate Edition</Title>
                    <Url>//www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/p/state-of-decay-2-ultimate-edition/9nsch45hz9hk</Url>
                    <ImageUrl>//store-images.s-microsoft.com/image/apps.50602.14365785075596216.2000000000013039869.e8c6dd03-ff3a-48fb-a8ad-479a95448240?w=150&amp;h=150</ImageUrl>
                    <Metas>
                        <Meta>
                            <Key>BigCatalogId</Key>
                            <Value>9NSCH45HZ9HK</Value>
                        </Meta>
                        <Meta>
                            <Key>ProductType</Key>
                            <Value>Game</Value>
                        </Meta>
                        <Meta>
                            <Key>Icon</Key>
                            <Value>//store-images.s-microsoft.com/image/apps.50602.14365785075596216.2000000000013039869.e8c6dd03-ff3a-48fb-a8ad-479a95448240</Value>
                        </Meta>
                        <Meta>
                            <Key>ImageHeight</Key>
                            <Value>1080</Value>
                        </Meta>
                        <Meta>
                            <Key>ImageWidth</Key>
                            <Value>1080</Value>
                        </Meta>
                        <Meta>
                            <Key>ImageType</Key>
                            <Value>BoxArt</Value>
                        </Meta>
                        <Meta>
                            <Key>AppBgColor</Key>
                            <Value>#FFFFFF</Value>
                        </Meta>
                    </Metas>
                </Product>
                <Product>
                    <Curated>false</Curated>
                    <Source>Games</Source>
                    <Title>State of Decay 2: Doomsday Pack</Title>
                    <Url>//www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/p/state-of-decay-2-doomsday-pack/9pcqkkwf0zwp</Url>
                    <ImageUrl>//store-images.s-microsoft.com/image/apps.6519.14169313509850372.ade11659-c080-431a-9d6b-6933c4264efb.20f0ebab-bd4f-41c3-a514-7f9347266072?w=150&amp;h=150</ImageUrl>
                    <Metas>
                        <Meta>
                            <Key>BigCatalogId</Key>
                            <Value>9PCQKKWF0ZWP</Value>
                        </Meta>
                        <Meta>
                            <Key>ProductType</Key>
                            <Value>Durable</Value>
                        </Meta>
                        <Meta>
                            <Key>Icon</Key>
                            <Value>//store-images.s-microsoft.com/image/apps.6519.14169313509850372.ade11659-c080-431a-9d6b-6933c4264efb.20f0ebab-bd4f-41c3-a514-7f9347266072</Value>
                        </Meta>
                        <Meta>
                            <Key>ImageHeight</Key>
                            <Value>1080</Value>
                        </Meta>
                        <Meta>
                            <Key>ImageWidth</Key>
                            <Value>1080</Value>
                        </Meta>
                        <Meta>
                            <Key>ImageType</Key>
                            <Value>BoxArt</Value>
                        </Meta>
                    </Metas>
                </Product>
                <Product>
                    <Curated>false</Curated>
                    <Source>Devices</Source>
                    <Title>State of Decay 2 for Xbox One</Title>
                    <Url>//www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/p/state-of-decay-2-for-xbox-one/8p2fgp3bf0fc</Url>
                    <ImageUrl>//img-prod-cms-rt-microsoft-com.akamaized.net/cms/api/am/imageFileData/RE1Tc21?ver=3d93&amp;w=272&amp;h=223&amp;o=f&amp;m=6&amp;f=jpg</ImageUrl>
                    <Metas>
                        <Meta>
                            <Key>BigCatalogId</Key>
                            <Value>8P2FGP3BF0FC</Value>
                        </Meta>
                        <Meta>
                            <Key>ProductType</Key>
                            <Value>Devices</Value>
                        </Meta>
                        <Meta>
                            <Key>Icon</Key>
                            <Value>https://img-prod-cms-rt-microsoft-com.akamaized.net/cms/api/am/imageFileData/RE1Tc21?ver=3d93</Value>
                        </Meta>
                        <Meta>
                            <Key>ImageHeight</Key>
                            <Value>1540</Value>
                        </Meta>
                        <Meta>
                            <Key>ImageWidth</Key>
                            <Value>1189</Value>
                        </Meta>
                        <Meta>
                            <Key>ImageType</Key>
                            <Value>tile</Value>
                        </Meta>
                    </Metas>
                </Product>
            </Suggests>
        </SuggestResults>
        <SuggestResults>
            <Source>microsoft-terms</Source>
            <FromCache>false</FromCache>
            <Type>term</Type>
            <Suggests>
                <Term>
                    <Curated>false</Curated>
                    <Txt>state of decay year one survival edition</Txt>
                </Term>
                <Term>
                    <Curated>false</Curated>
                    <Txt>state of decay year one survival edition for xbox one</Txt>
                </Term>
                <Term>
                    <Curated>false</Curated>
                    <Txt>state of decay for xbox 360 download code</Txt>
                </Term>
            </Suggests>
        </SuggestResults>
    </ResultSets>
    <ErrorSets>
        <SuggestErrorSet>
            <Source>iris-products</Source>
            <Message>Code: 2040. Message: Demand source returns error (Name: GN_ps, Error: No eligible content.).</Message>
        </SuggestErrorSet>
    </ErrorSets>
</SuggestResponse>
```

Sometimes happens that SuggestResults to be a single element instead of array. So I created an `JsonProperty` as object and do trick in `ParsedSuggestResult` property.

I have the following class:

```
public sealed class MsQueryXmlDetailResponse
    {

        public Suggestresponse SuggestResponse { get; set; }

        public class Suggestresponse
        {
            public string xmlnsxsd { get; set; }
            public string xmlnsxsi { get; set; }
            public string Query { get; set; }
            public Resultsets ResultSets { get; set; }
            public Errorsets ErrorSets { get; set; }
        }

        public class Resultsets
        {
            [JsonProperty("SuggestResults")]
            public object SuggestResultItems { get; set; }

            public Suggestresult[] ParsedSuggestResult {
                get
                {
                    if(SuggestResultItems is Suggestresult)
                    {
                        return new Suggestresult[] { SuggestResultItems as Suggestresult };
                    }

                    var result = SuggestResultItems as Suggestresult[];
                    if(result != null)
                    {
                        return result;
                    }

                    return new Suggestresult[] { JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Suggestresult>(SuggestResultItems.ToString()) };
                }
            }
        }

        public class Suggestresult
        {
            public string Source { get; set; }
            public string FromCache { get; set; }
            public string Type { get; set; }
            public Suggests Suggests { get; set; }
        }

        public class Suggests
        {
            public Product[] Product { get; set; }
            public Term[] Term { get; set; }
        }

        public class Product
        {
            public string Curated { get; set; }
            public string Source { get; set; }
            public string Title { get; set; }
            public string Url { get; set; }
            public string ImageUrl { get; set; }
            public Metas Metas { get; set; }
        }

        public class Metas
        {
            public Meta[] Meta { get; set; }
        }

        public class Meta
        {
            public string Key { get; set; }
            public string Value { get; set; }
        }

        public class Term
        {
            public string Curated { get; set; }
            public string Txt { get; set; }
        }

        public class Errorsets
        {
            public Suggesterrorset SuggestErrorSet { get; set; }
        }

        public class Suggesterrorset
        {
            public string Source { get; set; }
            public string Message { get; set; }
        }
}
```

and I used Newtonsoft.Json to deserialize xml string format to a class (defined above):

```
var xmldoc = new XmlDocument();
xmldoc.LoadXml(response);
var fromXml = JsonConvert.SerializeXmlNode(xmldoc);
MsQueryXmlDetailResponse data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MsQueryXmlDetailResponse>(fromXml);
```

But I got:

> Cannot deserialize the current JSON array into type because the type
>   requires a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to deserialize
>   correctly. To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON object
>   (e.g. {"name":"value"}) or change the deserialized type to an array or
>   a type that implements a collection interface (e.g. ICollection,
>   IList) like List that can be deserialized from a JSON array.
>   JsonArrayAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to
>   deserialize from a JSON array.

What should I do here ? If I do `SuggestResult[]` instead of `object` and xml response contains one SuggestResult element then error occur again.

Comment: The first thing you could do is check the JSON string in `fromXml` and find where it disagrees with your object model...

Comment: Instead of going from XML to JSON and using JSON deserializaiton, why not deserialize the XML directly into your class instance? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: what happen if I got array of SuggestResult and what happen if I got one element of SuggestResult ? Will be treat as array with one element ?

Comment: Why don't you try and see what happens if you feed your code with an XML containing one SuggestResult?

Comment: I got `<SuggestResponse xmlns=''>` was not expected ...

Answer (score 0):

The serializer doesn't know what to convert those objects to so by default, it will return objects deriving from `JToken`. It knows nothing about the `Suggesresult` type for the `SuggestResults` property.

You need to annotate that property to give a hint to what to deserialize to. But given that it can be one or more items, you will have to create a converter for it. Fortunately that should be simple to implement.

```
class SingleOrArrayJsonConverter<T> : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType) => objectType == typeof(List<T>);
    public override bool CanRead => true;
    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var token = JToken.Load(reader);
        switch (token.Type)
        {
        case JTokenType.Array:
            return ToObject<List<T>>(token);
        default:
            return new List<T> { ToObject<T>(token) };
        }
    }
    private TObj ToObject<TObj>(JToken token) => token.ToObject<TObj>();

    public override bool CanWrite => false;
    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer) => throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

Then you could just provide a more appropriate type on the object itself.

```
public class Resultsets
{
    [JsonProperty("SuggestResults")]
    [JsonConverter(typeof(SingleOrArrayJsonConverter<Suggestresult>))]
    public List<Suggestresult> SuggestResultItems { get; set; }

    public Suggestresult[] ParsedSuggestResult => SuggestResultItems.ToArray();
}
```